# Problema com Método em Classe JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Criei uma classe em JavaScript e utilizei o  `var` para deixar os atributos encapsulados, porém quando eu uso o método `setNome()` ele não funciona.

```js
class AA {
  constructor(nome, idade) {
    var nome = nome;
    var idade = idade || "";

    this.getNome = () => { return nome; };
    this.setNome = (nome) => { nome = nome; };
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `this.nome`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você está usando classes, não tem porquê fazer esse tipo de coisa. Crie métodos e propriedades usando o `this`, que ficarão encapsulados nas instâncias da classe. Algo assim:

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  
  setName(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }
}

const u = new User('Unnamed');
console.log(u.getName());

u.setName('Luiz');
console.log(u.getName());
```

Se você não quiser classes, pode usar um tipo de *factory function*:

```js
function createUser() {
  let name = 'Unnamed';
  
  const setName = (newName) => name = newName;
  const getName = () => name;
  
  return {
    setName,
    getName
  };
}

const u = createUser();

u.setName('Luiz');
console.log(u.getName());
```

<sup>Pessoalmente, eu prefiro essa segunda abordagem na maioria das vezes, já que acho mais claro. Além disso, não há todas aquelas confusões trazidas pelo `this` do JavaScript.</sup>